# Extends base html issue

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I got main page at index.html. I want to transfer my template to base.html. I used `{% extends 'base.html' %}` at index.html, but it doesn't see this file with *Unresolved template reference ''base.html'' *
folder of base.html: *project/templates*

*myproject/app/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mainsite/index.html')
```

*project/app/urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='home'),

]
```

*project/setting.py*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainsite.apps.MainsiteConfig',
]
```

*project/url.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainsite.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your views could you try to edit like,I tend to think it the template path declared wrong .

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```